# rectangle stroke line not scaling

Tags: flash

Whenever I resize an object the width of the stroke does not get resized along with it. It was working fine the other day, which leads me to believe I turned off something. I'm unsure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you select a shape and look in the Properties panel, there is a Scale setting under the Fill & Stroke tab. This controls how the stroke behaves when the clip is scaled/

- Normal scales the stroke along with the clip.
- Vertical only scales the stroke vertically.
- Horizontal only scale the stroke horizontally.
- None does not scale the stroke, regardless of the clip's scale.

Comment: I'll have to look again when I'm at home, but I couldn't find that when I looked before.